# Scrape America's Career InfoNet

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've got employer IDs, which can be utilized get the business area:

https://www.careerinfonet.org/employ4.asp?emp_id=558742391

The HTML contains the data in tr/td tables:

```
    Business Description:
         Exporters (Whls)   Primary Industry:Other Miscellaneous Durable Goods Merchant Wholesalers
     Related Industry:Sporting and Athletic Goods Manufacturing
```

So I would like to get

- Exporters (Whls)
- Other Miscellaneous Durable Goods Merchant Wholesalers
- Sporting and Athletic Goods Manufacturing

My example code looks like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.careerinfonet.org/employ4.asp?emp_id=558742391")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('td', class_='content')    
for td in div.find_all('td'):
    print(td.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to preface this by saying that this technique is fairly sloppy, but it gets the job done assuming each page you scrape has a similar set up.

Your code is excellent for accessing the page itself, I simply add a check for every element to determine if it is the `"Business Description"`, or the `"Primary"` or `"Related Industry"`. Then you can access the appropriate element and use that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.careerinfonet.org/employ4.asp?emp_id=558742391")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

div = soup.find('td', class_='content')  
lst = div.find_all('td')  
for td in lst:
    if td.text == "Business Description:":
        print(lst[lst.index(td)+1].text)
    if td.text == "Primary Industry:":
        print(lst[lst.index(td)+1].text)
    if td.text == "Related Industry:":
        print(lst[lst.index(td)+1].text)
```

The other small modification I made is putting `div.find_all('td')` in a list that can then be indexed, to access the element you want.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I'm very grateful. May you please also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47212951/scrape-wood-industry-database-with-beautifulsoup ?