# Scrape wood industry database with BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the sawmill owner (after "Owned by:") from https://www.sawmilldatabase.com/sawmill.php?id=1282 with BeautifulSoup.

I've tried to adapt [this very similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184202/scrape-americas-career-infonet), but it doesn't work for a reason I don't understand.

```
<td>
   <a href="../company.php?id=729">AKD Softwoods </a>
</td>
```

Python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.sawmilldatabase.com/sawmill.php?id=1282')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

lst = soup.find_all('TD')
for td in lst:
    if td.text == "Owned by":
        print("yes")
        print(lst[lst.index(td)+1].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used regex to help me reach to the element you're looking for.

Code:

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.sawmilldatabase.com/sawmill.php?id=1282')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('a', href=re.compile('company.php')).text)
```

Output:

```
AKD Softwoods
```

Answer (score 0):

To address the code you submitted, the reason you are not successful is that you use `if td.text == "Owned by"` as your conditional. While this seems like it may work, it will never return what you want because the website you are scraping places the sawmill owner after `"Owned by: "`. (If you [inspect the webpage](https://zapier.com/blog/inspect-element-tutorial/), you will see the `<td>` tag is `<td>Owned by: </d>`).

While the difference between `"Owned by"` and `"Owned by: "` seems negligible, it makes all the difference to your program. Simply by changing your code to `if td.text == "Owned by: ":`, you will get the correct response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.sawmilldatabase.com/sawmill.php?id=1282')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

lst = soup.find_all('td')
for td in lst:
    if td.text == "Owned by: ":
        print("yes")
        print(lst[lst.index(td)+1].text)
```

Alternatively, you could also use `if "Owned by" in td.text:` as your conditional, but this is not exactly ideal, in the event there is another `<td>` tag with that information in it.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Oh and also don't capitalize `TD` in `lst = soup.find_all('TD')`.

Answer (score 0):

How about the below approach!! If you comply with this usage `if sth.text=="sth else: "`, the main problem is that the text within inverted comma has to be identical to the one stored in the webpage. If you happen to use `if sth.text=="sth else:"` this, it will no longer work because the extra space from it's last portion has been taken out. Try this instead:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://www.sawmilldatabase.com/sawmill.php?id=1282").text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select("table td"):
    if "Owned by:" in items.text:
        name = items.find_next_sibling().text
        print(name)
```

Output:

```
AKD Softwoods
```